# Compare time complexity of Python API

Tags: python

I have two pieces of code written in python.

For A code, the time complexity is O (n^2) because remove exists inside the iterator.

And since the join method exists in return, the time complexity of the line is O (n), so I think the time complexity of the whole code is O (n^2).

The collections.Counter used in the B code has a time complexity of O (n), which I think is O (n^2) because it is used with the join method in one line.

But the two codes seem to have different performances.

If ignore constant time, why is there a performance difference in the two codes?

**A**

```
def solution(participant, completion):
    for i in  completion: participant.remove(i)
    return "".join(participant)
```

**B**

```
import collections
def solution(participant, completion):
    return "".join(collections.Counter(participant) - collections.Counter(completion))
```

Comment: The first is O(m*n) where m, n are the sizes of the two different containers. The second is O(m + n). You're not repeating the `Counter` part in the join over multiple iterations, join only runs over the `Counter` result once, so it's not quadratic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution has complexity `O(m * n + k)` with `m`, `n` la the size of the two lists and `k=m-n`.
The second solution has complex computation `O(m + n + k)`.

Furthermore you have to take into account the implementation aspects, `Counter` is written in C/C++ and `'-'` operation is written in C/C++, your code instead the loop on `m` is in python, the operations on `n` of `remove()` in C/C++